# Is there a way to create an alert when an Azure SQL Database backup fails?

Tags: database, azure-sql-database, backup

Does anyone know how to create an alert when, for whatever reason, an Azure SQL Database backup fails to complete?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Azure Monitor service** to create alert for Backup failure.

1. Search for `Monitor` in Azure Portal. Click on `alerts` under Monitor.

[image]

2. Click on `+Create` -> `Alert rule`.
3. Click `+ Scope` and select the required fields.

[image]

4. Under `Condition` tab, select the option `Activity log` and select Signal name as `Export an existing database` as shown in below image.

[image]

5. Select the alert logic.

[image]

5. Under `Action` tab, create a New action group or use existing group.
6. In the action group, create an alerts like Email, SMS or Voice call and click on OK.

[image]

Comment: Won't this just alert on the execution of a backup, not an actual "backup failed"?

Comment: You can select `alert logic` under Condition tab in step 4. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Wahoo. Easier than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: Looks like I'm not able to customize the severity of the alert. This particular alert raises as a Severity 4 and I'm needing it to be higher.

Comment: Looks like this only applies to exporting to a bacpac.

Comment: So this is what you have asked, right? If you want to change the alert condition, use the different signal in step 4.

Comment: If you are trying anything new and stuck in that, please create a new question and let the community member answer for it.

Comment: It's the same question. We have not found a way to alert on an actual backup failure, not an export to a bacpac file.